# TexLive on Heroku etc. - What are my options ?

Tags: heroku, amazon-ec2, tex

I am trying to build a Rails application that would internally invoke LaTeX
to stitch together TeX files to generate documents on the fly. Not necessarily PDF.
Just TeX -> DVI -> PS would do it for me.

My best guess is that I would need to host 2 separate code-bases, one for 
Rails code ( the standard $RAILS_ROOT ) and (possibly) a separate directory structure 
for hosting the TeX files ( which is also code in a way ). And as I see it,
the Rails app would make system calls to LaTeX (`latex <options> <files>`) 
on the TeX files to do what I want it to do

I was wondering, therefore, if you guys could help me decide what the 
best hosting option could be for the above setup ( unless, you think that
the setup itself should be different )

I know that something like Heroku would allow me to host the Rails bit easily. 
But as far as I can tell, their servers do not have full TexLive installation which I need.
I have asked them if they could install TexLive on their servers. But assuming
they don't entertain one off requests, what are my options ?

Do I then need to recreate my local setup from scratch on something like Amazon's EC2 ?
Any pointers on available options and the tasks they would entail would be most 
helpful.

Thanks 
Abhinav

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to make it work on Heroku but you may need to write a custom buildpack which includes/installs the latex binaries:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Answer (score 0):

There is already a buildpack for TeX and it works for me perfectly:
https://github.com/holiture/heroku-buildpack-tex